# C++ total right alignment in output

Tags: c++, shell

my problem is the following: I would like to align an output text to the total right of my output shell when executing. I can not use the standard `std::setw()` and `std::right` manipulator, because I wish the output is always at the right boundary, no matter how much large is the shell.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: From the standard C++'s point of view, output is a stream, so it doesn't have a "total right." You will have to look into a terminal library, such as `ncurses`.

Comment: You can simply get the width of the shell first.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Angew, output is a stream, so it doesn't have a *total right*. To achieve the goal, you can simply get the width of the shell first, and then use `setw()` and `right`:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
int width = csbi.dwSize.X;

string str = "string you want to print";
cout << right << setw(width) << str << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answers! At the end I solved with:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

....

struct winsize w;
ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
int column_width = w.ws_col;
cout << setw(column_width) << "Thank you everybody";

....
```